# Pass quoted argument string to Start-Process in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to very simply run an executable and pass a file path in as the first argument. In DOS, this would be the command:

```
import.exe "C:\Some Path\With\Spaces.txt"
```

By placing the path in quotes, the path is correctly parsed as the first token into the executable.

In PowerShell I'm using this:

```
$feeds = dir 'T:\Documents\Company\Product Development\Data
foreach ($feed in $feeds) { start -FilePath import.exe -ArgumentList $feed.FullName }
```

The problem with the Start-Process cmdlet in PowerShell is that it uses a string array for arguments, so the path is broken up and sent to the executable as separate tokens, or effectively as a string without those important quotes.

Adding quotes to my PowerShell command line force "$feed.FullName" to be treated literally.

And double quotes "" make PowerShell not see anything in the argument list. "The argument is null or empty." it tells me.

I expect that this is a known headache and has had a known workaround from day one.

Thanks

Luke

**UPDATES AND RESPONSES**

```
foreach ($feed in $feeds) { Invoke-Expression "start import.exe `"$feed.FullName`"" }
```

Note: I'm using Start since despite setting my location to the folder in which import.exe resides, PowerShell seems to have been written to look for executables in the file-system current location.

The variable gets interpreted with the .FullName as a literal string!:

```
filename.txt.FullName
```

This one:

```
foreach ($feed in $feeds) { Invoke-Expression "C:\Users\Public\Documents\~Main\Data.Importer\Data.Importer\bin\Release\import.exe ($feed.FullName)" }
```

Results in:

```
Invoke-Expression : Unexpected token '_data.txt.FullName' in expression or statement.
```

Interestingly, on its own, this works:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\~Main\Data.Importer\Data.Importer\bin\Release\import.exe $feed.FullName
```

But this:

```
foreach ($feed in $feeds) { Invoke-Expression C:\Users\Public\Documents\~Main\Vuplan\Evoq.Vuplan.Data.Epg.Importer\Evoq.Vuplan.Data.Epg.Importer\bin\Release\import.exe $feed.FullName }
```

Results in this:

```
Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'T:\Documents\Company\Product Development\Data\3112_data.txt'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Invoke-Expression "start import.exe '$($feed.FullName)'"
```

Comment: This works. Thanks Shay - and Bartek @bielawb on Twitter - who both managed to work out how to stop the $feed variable being detached from its .FullName property.

Answer (score 3):

This command works for me:

```
import.exe '"C:\Some Path\With\Spaces.txt"'
```

Make sure you nest the double quotes inside single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing can be worked around with the `invoke-expression` cmdlet

```
invoke-expression "import.exe `"C:\Some Path\With\Spaces.txt`""
```

The backticks will be interpreted and should start import.exe with the specified string.

Comment: I was too eager, this actually doesn't work. Still fighting.

Answer (score 2):

After assigning all paths to variables, the `Start-Process` command can be used like this:

`` Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $toolPath -ArgumentList `"$arg1`",`"$arg2`" ``

By using `" the arguments get passed quoted to the application, i.e.:
[Screenshot of an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS28Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Calling **DOS** commands in **Powershell** directly.

For example:

```
cmd.exe /c start import.exe $myParameter
```